# Samsung booting to bios (no ubuntu) after ubuntu 14 update

Tags: boot, kubuntu, kde, xfce

I updated ubuntu on a friends' laptop and now when it turns on, it shows the BIOS (not GRUB like before) with the option to enter "`windows boot manager`" which is nonsense because the laptop does not have windows or other partitions.

This all happened after updated + installing KDE and XFCE desktops.

Can someone help, please?

Comment: The only thing I can offer is to do a boot repair. Can you make a boot repair usb live session from another machine and use that?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried that already, and the boot repair did say it repaired something. However, after rebooting, the computer still shows the BIOS without any working option.
I tried both methods without success
https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Comment: Exactly which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I have ubuntu 14.04